# can we create a cursor which is an inter-merge of 2 or more cursors ?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two Cursors from 2 different queries that have different projections,

```
    cursor_1 and cursor_2
```

and I am using a cursor loader to feed a Cursor adapter, that has different row views that change according to the position, Now my question is, can I merge the cursors Vertically. However, not like MergeCursor does -a complete cursor at a time-, I want them to Inter-merge

```
   5 rows from the first cursor then 1 from the second one
```

and then repeat this sequence indefinitely

can this be done?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in extending `AbstractCursor` or `CursorWrapper`, but imho the first is better in your case

Comment: thx, I'll look into those now

Comment: first look into `AbstractCursor`, `CursorWrapper` is used when you `"[...] extend a cursor while overriding only a subset of its methods."`, [this](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/MergeCursor.java) can be useful for a sample implementation

Comment: @pskink, one More question, when I extended Abstract Cursor ... mPos was deprecated, what should I use instead ?

Comment: what does documentation say?

Comment: ok, I used moveToPosition(-1) and it works correctly